# How to pass web3 client from server to client in next.js?

Tags: web3js, truffle, security, web3-providers, nextjs

I spent all day (meh, not a record (but I'm not finished yet lol)) trying to pass the web3 instance to the client side of my app. Why would I use it on the server side? Well, to keep my wallet mnemonics safe... I don't get it.. why would anyone use it on the client side exposing their wallet mnemonics or privatekeys (...aaand I just realized that private keys will be exposed anyways.. well that's bad.. let's pretend they won't for now. So here's the server side code code:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

import HDWalletProvider from '@truffle/hdwallet-provider';
import { hdkey } from 'ethereumjs-wallet';
const bip39 = require('bip39');
import Web3 from 'web3';

import { decycle } from '../../lib/utils/Cycle';

const WALLET_COUNT = 50;
const MNEMONIC_PHRASE = 'myMnemPhrase';
const INFURA_API_KEY = 'myApiKey';

const generateAddressesFromSeed = async (seed: string, walletCount: number) => {
    let hdwallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(seed));
    let wallet_hdpath = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/";

    let allAccs = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < walletCount; i++) {
        let wallet = hdwallet.derivePath(wallet_hdpath + i).getWallet();
        let address = '0x' + wallet.getAddress().toString('hex');
        let privateKey = wallet.getPrivateKey().toString('hex');
        allAccs.push({ value: address, label: address, privateKey });
    }
    return allAccs;
};

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const body = JSON.parse(req.body);

        const assignRpc = (rpc: string[] | string) => {
            if (Array.isArray(rpc)) {
                const check = body.rpc.find((rpc: string) => /infura/i.test(rpc));
                if (check) return `${check.slice(0, -17)}${INFURA_API_KEY}`;
                else return rpc[0];
            } else return rpc;
        };

        const rpc = assignRpc(body.rpc);

        const provider = new HDWalletProvider({
            mnemonic: {
                phrase: MNEMONIC_PHRASE,
            },
            numberOfAddresses: WALLET_COUNT,
            providerOrUrl: rpc,
        });

        const allAccs = await generateAddressesFromSeed(MNEMONIC_PHRASE, WALLET_COUNT);
        const web3 = decycle(new Web3(<any>provider));

        res.json({ web3, allAccs });
    }
}
```

So when I try sending the response I get "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON".
I tried almost everything, if to use a function from MDN or many npm module that can do circular structure to JSON, it just removes data from the object and it becomes useless rather quickly, so as you can see in my code I'm already using the decycle and retrocycle function from that old and famous git repository, but it seems like all the npm modules are also using it because I don't see a difference, the web3 object is still incomplete and has almost no methods etc in short it is useless...
here's a little screen of what the client gets:

> [image: not so much complete web3 object that client receives]

As you can see there's a lot of missing methods and other important stuff.. So the question is... hoooooooooooooooooooooooowwwwwwwwwwww or is it even possiblle to pass the web3 client or any circular structured object in the network request?.......... Thanks a lot in advance:)

Comment: I just realized that maybe I should not pass web3 client to anywhere.. just to pass what it returns, and just to implement all inside of the api. maybe..

Comment: yes, everything should be on the server side at least for security